# I can't see any images of my wicket project, I just see the image name?

Tags: image, tomcat, maven, text, wicket

I'm building a web project with Wicket, maven and hibernate. I run it with Tomcat 7. I'm actually using a free CSS for the HTML. The thing is that yesterday everything was working fine, and today I start the project as allways and I see that I can't see the images of the web, I just see the images names. I've been searching for the solution for a long time, and it seems that I'm the only one that has this problem :S. I leave a picture so you can see how it looks like the problem and see if you can help me with this... Please help me!

This is a capture of what I see when I execute the project:

http://postimage.org/image/8nb54we3b/

And this is a capture of how it has to look like if it worked normally:

http://postimage.org/image/5kfgyn5g7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it was because of the function "mountResource" that it stripped all my CSS work. So I delete it and now it works ok

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't change anything try to clean the tomcat, or deploying again

Comment: Why did you voted this question with -1????? If you don't know how to help me, just don't answer... ¬¬